# Removing www. from a sub domain via .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I currently have the following which:

1. Removes www. from urls and redirects to https://somedomain.com
2. Makes redirects http:// requests to https://

This works great, here is the code...

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The problem I am now faced with is.. how can I remove www. from the sub domain
e.g.    https://www.subdomain.maindomain.com and redirect it to
https://subdomain.maindomain.com

Hope someone can asisst

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

Comment: %1 or %2 it's: `^(?:www\.)?(.+)`

Comment: @Croises that was a typo. thanks for reviewing the code.

Comment: Thanks, is this to replace the last line of the code or an addition to mine (add at the bottom)?

Answer (score 0):

To remove WWW from a subdomain just use the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
```